# Double border style not working on outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, outlook-2010

When sending an html email, i'm trying to set a double border to separate some rows on a table.

My first try was an inline style:

```
style='border-top:double'
```

using style='border-collapse: collapse'

It worked perfectly on gmail. But in Outlook the only difference was a blank space instead of the second line.

Also, I tried

```
style='border-top:double windowtext 2px'
```

and

```
style='border-top:3px double #CCC;'
```

And still have one line between rows.

Comment: For now i added an empty cell between the rows. It work, but... you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...

I had to set the style for both rows i wanted to set the double line in between,
In the bottom and top.
Using just one works on most of the browser i tested. (except IE 6)

So, this is how i did it:

...

```
<table style='border-collapse: collapse'>
    <tr> 
      <td style='border-botton:double'> 1st row </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td style='border-top:double'> 2nd row </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...